stability.ai 3.5 API - image: input not instance of Blob
I am trying to use the Stable Diffusion API (via stability.ai) models SD3.5, with their api details here: https://platform.stability.ai/docs/api-reference#tag/Generate/paths/~1v2beta~1stable-image~1generate~1sd3/post
My code is in PHP
Mode text-to-image works great, no issues at all.
However, when I try image-to-image I always get an error:
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image: input not instance of Blob' (length=33)
  public 'id' => string '620816a0b769aeb353780c8f6ff982b7' (length=32)
  public 'name' => string 'bad_request' (length=11)

I have tried reading (and sending) the image in multiple ways, via file_get_contents, file_read (binary and non binary), tested jpg, png images.
Out of desperation, I even did a previous call to text-to-image and then sent to image-to-image using the image string I got from the previous call, as it was, no modifications, but I still get the error "image: input not instance of Blob".
My machine is Windows, so I also tested on linux (to discard any OS specific file issues), but the result is exactly the same.
Anyone has any ideas? I have been trying for a week with zero luck.
I appreciate your help!

Just replying to myself, in case someone comes across this: had to use new CURLFile() before submitting it via post. Thanks Google for that!
